# Пароль html, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо поставить пароль html на страницу. Пароль должен быть именно в коде. Пароль должен не перебрасывать на другую страницу, а открывать «скрытую» часть.
Возможно, такой вопрос уже был. Не знаю наверняка.

Comment: Ну и хотелось бы для начала увидеть ваши наброски)

Comment: Ну и, соответственно, если ответ помог, отметьте его)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вот так (накидал на скорую руку, без варианта действия при неверном пароле):

```js
let password = 'admin';

let passwordButton = document.querySelector('.password-button');
let hideButton = document.querySelector('.hide-button');

let hiddenPart = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

passwordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let userInput = prompt('Password?', '');
  if (userInput == password) {
    hiddenPart.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});

hideButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hiddenPart.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px -30px darksalmon, 0 0 100px -30px darksalmon, 0 0 100px -40px darksalmon, 0 0 100px -40px darksalmon, 0 0 100px -40px darksalmon;
}

.wrapper.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="password-button">Ввести пароль</button>
  <button class="hide-button">Спрятать содержимое</button>
  <div class="wrapper hidden">
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S. Добавил кнопку для того, чтобы прятать контент

Comment: Где именно изменить необходимый пароль возможно?

Comment: В самом коде. Вы же сами попросили, чтобы он в коде был